# Selected class throws navigation menu off

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have my navigation menu working perfectly. But when I apply the selected class to any of my items in the navigation list other than the 'Home' link, it pushes my navigation menu into two lines. I've tried everything but can't seem to figure the problem out.

Also this only happens in Chrome. I tried it on Firefox on Windows and Mac and it worked perfectly.

I tried adding a slash to the end of About and that seemed to push the 'About' word out but keep the slash still on the second line.

Can anyone please help? I can't seem to figure this out.

A picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: error]

Here is my menu code with the home selected:

```
<div id="navigation"> <!-- Start navigation -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home \</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="collection.html">Collection <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

And here is the code with the About link selected:

```
<div id="navigation"> <!-- Start navigation -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="collection.html">Collection <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video <span>\</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="selected" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- End navigation -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#navigation { clear: both; float: right; margin-top: 30px; }
#navigation ul li { display: inline; margin-right: 10px; }
#navigation ul li a { font-family: "Lucida Console"; font-size: 19px; color: #B3B3B3; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; }
#navigation ul li a span { font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle; }
#navigation ul li a.selected { color: #6a6a6a; }
```

Comment: Totally not sure about this so won't post as anwer, but have you tried giving #navigation a specific width, or have it set to width:100% in your style declaration?

Comment: I have tried setting #navigation to 100% but that didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a class being applied for .selected that you are missing. The about link looks larger to me. Have you inspected in Firebug?

Comment: I noticed that too, but Firebug doesn't seem to show anything except a line-height that the .selected class inherits. Could that be causing it?

Comment: I noticed that webkit browsers are adding a user-agent stylesheet and I think that's what's causing it. The problem doesn't occur in Firefox or IE. Is there anyway I can stop this?

Comment: If possible, can you replicate on JSFiddle. Also, are you using a CSS reset? Here is what I generally use: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/ (I am not saying it is the best, just what I am familiar with)

Comment: Here it is on JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/AMnbZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/AMnbZ/) and I'm using the HTML 5 Boilerplate CSS.

Comment: I changed display inline to inline-block and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/vPKJs/7/